# How to remove gridlines from interact_plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, interaction, gridlines

I'm trying to remove gridlines from an `interact_plot` in R Studio, which I understand uses plotting from ggplot2.

I have tried the following code from ggplot2:

```r
interact_plot(
  MC_Feat_Sit, 
  pred =  Mean_Mor_Con2, 
  modx = Agreement2, 
  modx.values = c(1, 4, 7), 
  x.label = "Moral Conviction", 
  y.label = "Situational Attributions", 
  legend.main = "Agreement", 
  modx.labels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Neutral", "Strongly Agree"), 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
)
```

But I get this error message:

> Mean_Mor_Con2 and Agreement2 and theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) are not
> included in an interaction with one another in the model.Error in names(modxvals2) <- modx.labels :
> attempt to set an attribute on NULL

I also get the same error message when trying to use a theme (e.g. `theme_bw()`).

Any help is much appreciated!

[This is the graph I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUJZG.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `interact_plot` returns an object of type ggplot and then it can be modified afterwards and not directly inside this function:

```
plt <- interact_plot(
  MC_Feat_Sit, 
  pred =  Mean_Mor_Con2, 
  modx = Agreement2, 
  modx.values = c(1, 4, 7), 
  x.label = "Moral Conviction", 
  y.label = "Situational Attributions", 
  legend.main = "Agreement", 
  modx.labels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Neutral", "Strongly Agree")
)

plt <- plt + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())

plt
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response @danloo. I tried your code and it doesn't give me an error code but unfortunately it gives me the same plots as before (with light grey gridlines). Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the produced image. A reproducible example with data everyone has will help us as well.

Comment: I've added the produced image to the original post. I'm having trouble exporting my dataset from R (with all the measures created) back into excel or a CSV but if my image doesn't help I'll try again.

Comment: I updated the answer. It's `panel.grid.major`. I recommend to use [writexl](https://docs.ropensci.org/writexl/) to export a data frame to excel. CSV does not keep the format so there might be some importing issues.

Comment: Yep that worked! Thanks very much for your help @danlooo !!